# Detect Cellular Data Usage

Tags: ios, xcode, networking

How could I detect when a Wifi connection becomes unavailable and a cellular data (EDGE/3G) connection is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist an example-app from apple. Just take a look at that.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html